# How do i make multiple columns of lines using a loaded image in Processing?

Tags: java, for-loop, processing

I've made a code in processing that uploaded an image from data and used this image to make a line in processing, kind of like how you can use an organic looking brush in photoshop, except I want the program to draw the line for me.

I want to be able to have the program draw up to 16 lines, but I'm testing with only five lines drawn right now. To do this, I used a nested for loop. However, all that happens is that 4 lines are produced and only two are complete.

here is the code.

```
PImage brush;

void setup() {

    size(1000, 800);

    brush = loadImage("verticalOrganic.png");
    //load the file verticalOrganic from data. this is our "brush head".


    float i;
    float j;
    float distance;
    brush.resize(7, 0);
    for (j = 0; j < width; j += width / 5) { //this should create five rows, by updating j by 1/5 of 1000
        for (i = 0; i < height; i += distance) {  //distance determines the new position of the brush going down
            //the column.
            image(brush, j, i);  //when j updates, it should create a new column....should.

            distance = random(-10, (brush.height) * 3 / 4);

        }
        println("FINISHED"); //i thought what may be wrong was that j was not updating, so this tests that.
    }

}
```

Here is the file for the brush head/[(if you want to use it, you will have to change it to png. because imgur.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHrk2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch is increment for the inner loop with the `i` counter (`distance`) is problematic.

First of, it's defined as `float distance;` and has no initial value (defaults to 0), so the first time around `i` will remain 0.

The second, and larger problem is the value distance gets assigned to:

```
distance = random(-10, (brush.height) * 3 / 4);
```

This means `distance` can (and will) have values smaller than 0.

When you apply `distance` as the loop increment (`i += distance`) that means you can move in the wrong direction (`distance` will be subtracted from `i` rather than added) which either you'd go over the same i values or even worse potentially getting stuck never exiting the loop as small (even negative values) of `i` will never satisfy the loop exit condition: `i < height;`

I'd recommend keeping distance to a positive value:

```
distance = random((brush.height) * 3 / 4);
```

Here's a slightly modified version of your program with an extra variable to count the number of `i` iterations called `iCount` (and using the jpg instead of the png):

```
PImage brush;

void setup() {

    size(1000, 800);

    brush = loadImage("uHrk2.jpg");
    //load the file verticalOrganic from data. this is our "brush head".


    float i;
    float j;
    float distance;
    brush.resize(7, 0);
    
    int iCount = 0;
    
    for (j = 0; j < width; j += width / 5) { //this should create five rows, by updating j by 1/5 of 1000
        for (i = 0; i < height; i += distance) {  //distance determines the new position of the brush going down
            //the column.
            image(brush, j, i);  //when j updates, it should create a new column....should.

            distance = random((brush.height) * 3 / 4);
            iCount++;
        }
        
        println(iCount, "i iterations, column index", j, "FINISHED"); //i thought what may be wrong was that j was not updating, so this tests that.
        iCount = 0;
    }

}
```

Notice the number `iCount` has per column when it uses positive numbers only and try changing that back to `distance = random(-10, (brush.height) * 3 / 4);` and notice how many more iterations are needed for `i` to reach `height`.

From an aesthetics point of view, maybe you do want the Y-axis (`i`) inner loop to oscillate between exiting and forever iterating ?
If so, you might want to think of visual ways of emphasising that.
Currently as each repetition occurs the latest image rendered at `i` will be drawn on top of any previous image rendered around that `i` position (erasing it's history).

There are probably multiple options, but here are two simple ways:

1. using [`blendMode()`](https://processing.org/reference/blendMode_.html): these are very similar to layer blend modes in Photoshop. In this case `DIFFERENCE`, `EXCLUSION` and `REPLACE` (if your png has an alpha channel).
2. using [`tint()`](https://processing.org/reference/tint_.html) to add transparency (e.g. `tint(255, 32);` this would set 32/255 opacity (%12.5))

This should be easy to do after you call `size()`:

```
  size(1000, 800);
  background(255);
  blendMode(EXCLUSION);
```

and produce a more glitchy look:

[image: exclusion blend mode demonstrating overlapping image]

Simply using:

```
  size(1000, 800);
  background(255);
  tint(255, 32);
```

will produce something like:

[image: 12.5% opacity applied via tint to highlight overlapping repeating images]

I'd added a minor x offset so the columns are centred:

```
PImage brush;

void setup() {

  size(1000, 800);
  background(255);
  tint(255, 32);

  brush = loadImage("uHrk2.jpg");

  //load the file verticalOrganic from data. this is our "brush head".
  

  float i;
  float j;
  float distance;
  brush.resize(14, 0);
  println(brush.height);

  int iCount = 0;
  
  int offsetX = width / 10;
  
  for (j = 0; j < width; j += width / 5) { //this should create five rows, by updating j by 1/5 of 1000
    for (i = 0; i < height; i += distance) {  //distance determines the new position of the brush going down
      //the column.
      image(brush, offsetX + j, i);  //when j updates, it should create a new column....should.

      distance = random(-10, (brush.height) * 3 / 4);
      iCount++;
    }

    println(iCount, "i iterations, column index", j, "FINISHED"); //i thought what may be wrong was that j was not updating, so this tests that.
    iCount = 0;
  }


  save("fade.jpg");
}
```

Notice how the areas where `i` goes back and forth (because of negative `distance` values) become darker. If you were to switch to `distance = random(-10, (brush.height) * 3 / 4);` there will less darker areas:

[image: 12.5% opacity overlapping images with less repeating i positions]